# Comparing Enumerable with enumerable in a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I want to compare lists and return common objects using LINQ.

I have the Catalogs Model which contains a collection of supplierMaterials

```
public partial class Catalogs{        
        public int IdCatalog { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SupplierMaterials> SupplierMaterials { get; set; }        
    }
```

Then I have the subsidiary Model which contains a collection of catalogs

```
public partial class Subsidiary{
        public int IdSubsidiary { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Catalogs> Catalogs { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have the SupplierMaterials Model

```
 public partial class SupplierMaterials{
        public int IdCatalog { get; set; }
        public int IdSupplierMaterials{ get; set; }
 }
```

I have a user that has an environmnet.
An environment has many subsidiaries, I want to make a linq query with all the suppliermaterials that are on the 
subsidiary of the user.
I have this linq query but I don't know how to make the where clause

```
var subsidiary = user.Environment.First().Subsidiary;
query = (from x in db.SupplierMaterials
         join y in db.Catalogs on x.IdCatalog equals y.IdCatalog
         where y.Subsidiary.Any(subsidiary => y.Subsidiary)
         select x);
```

How can I get all the supplierMaterials from all catalogs from every subsidiary for a given environment?

Comment: Unrelated, but `user.Environment.FirstOrDefault().Subsidiary` will throw an exception if `FirstOrDefault` returns null. If there will always be one, then you probably should use `First()`. Otherwise, you'll need a null check.

Comment: Environment always have one, already changed it to First()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Enumerable.SelectMany Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allows you to flatten the data. To get all SupplierMaterials you just need to flatten twice. Your code could look something like this:

```
var supplierMaterials = user.Environments.First().Subsidiarys
                         .SelectMany(x => 
                           x.Catalogs.SelectMany(y => 
                               y.SupplierMaterials));
```

Comment: This can also be done (probably easier to read, in fact) with query syntax, like Magu's solution.